# VirtualHost sets the url as abc.com/subdirectory/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin xxx@abc.com
            ServerName abc.com
            ServerAlias www.abc.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/
            <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog /var/logs/error_wp.log
            CustomLog /var/logs/access_wp.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

I had issues with Wordpress url, then I changed the url to abc.com and now Wordpress renders all pages correctly.

But when it comes to homepage, abc.com, it redirects to abc.com/wordpress/

So whenever I type abc.com in a browser, it redirects to abc.com/wordpress/

And it says "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Wonder where the issue might be.

I'm using default .htaccess for Wordpress. I use a static homepage. Except homepage all other pages work properly. I am able to login using abc.com/wp-admin/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pretty silly. I had set a static page as homepage, which had an entry in db as abc.com/wordpress/. So everytime I click homepage, it would search for abc.com/wordpress/wordpress, which doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your directory block should list the path relative to the root, not the absolute path.  See if this fixes it:

```
            <Directory />
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
            </Directory>
```

Also, you shouldn't include a trailing slash with your document root.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
```

Here's the entire corrected config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin xxx@abc.com
            ServerName abc.com
            ServerAlias www.abc.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
            <Directory />
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog /var/logs/error_wp.log
            CustomLog /var/logs/access_wp.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No that doesn't help. It turned out to a 404.

Comment: I got it working. The problem was pretty silly. I had set a static page as homepage, which had an entry in db as abc.com/wordpress/. So everytime I click homepage, it would search for abc.com/wordpress/wordpress, which doesn't actually exist. Thanks :)